# Replacing a disk in zpool

Tags: zfs

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 & Zfs Native. I created a zpool using the /dev/disk/by-id method, but I can no longer import zpool. When I try zpool status command I get the error message " no such pool " when I try " zpool import " It finds the pool & shows that one disk is missing or unavailable.

```
pool: tank
    id: 14496103743076187609
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing
    devices and try again.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-6X
```

config:

```
aNas6TB      UNAVAIL  missing device
  sdf        ONLINE
  sdh        ONLINE

Additional devices are known to be part of this pool, though their
exact configuration cannot be determined.
```

I have connected another drive of same size ( bad disk still in original place ) but I am having difficulty replacing bad disk with new one in zpool. I tried the following:

```
sudo zpool replace tank /dev/sdg /dev/sde

sudo zpool replace tank scsi-SATA_ST32000542AS_9XW04YRP scsi-SATA_ST2000DM001-9YN_S240FE7C

sudo zpool replace tank dev/sdg dev/sde
```

I get the same error message each time "cannot open 'tank': no such pool"

I am obviously doing something wrong and would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the process to replace a damaged drive are:

1. `zpool offline pool_name device_name`
2. Shutdown and replace drive
3. `zpool replace pool_name device_name`

The first one takes a *device_name* drive offline from a *pool_name* pool, you then replace the drive with a new one and tell Zfs to replace the drive *device_name* in in the pool *pool_name*.

**device_name** and **pool_name** are the names of your drive and pool shown in `zpool status`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply when I run zpool status I get no such pool

Comment: kk, the broken disk is still in the system right?

Comment: Hi Bruno yes the broken disk is still in the system

Comment: Take it offline using `zpool offline tank /devname` and replace that drive with a new one on that position, then boot up and place it online with `zpool online tank /devname`.

Comment: Hi Bruno, when I try Zpool offline command I get same no such pool error

Comment: `zpool list` shows anything?

Comment: Hi Bruno, zpool list shows " No pools available "

Comment: `zpool clear tank` should clear the status and force zfs to check the pool again, can you try that?

Comment: Hi Bruno, I get the same error message: no such pool

Comment: At this moment you can try to force the mount with `zpool import -f tank` but I am guessing it will fail. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Hi Bruno, it says " one or more devices is currently unavailable " yet as I say in original post when I run zpool import without specifying pool name it lists both my zpools & shows tank has 2 healthy disk & one missing. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Ok, as we both now native zfs in Linux is a bit outdated, I would recommend at the moment that you start using FreeBSD to try to rescue your zfs pool, http://mfsbsd.vx.sk/ has a live 9.0 small image with zfs (v28) support, download it, burn it to a CD or created a USB boot disk and use FreeBSD to try to import that pool. Keep in touch and let me know how it is going. If you are stuck just shoot out any information and don't forget to edit your question with further details, the more the merrier!

Comment: Thanks Bruno I will try that & let you know. Thanks again for your help

Comment: No worries, I have been in that situation also, lets hope it works (it did for me!).

Comment: Hi Bruno just a quick question, I am using ZFS for my Mythtv backend would you suggest I use Freebsd intead of ubuntu or run FreeBSD on ubuntu with virtualbox as I asm not sure how well Mythtv is supported in FreeBSB.

Comment: Well, if it is just because you want to try a nice new fs, and your data is not critical (I am assuming that since zfs for linux is very unstable and not speed optimized), then why not try btrfs? It has similar features and is faster and more than stable compared with zfs for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may have been the same as mine as I was getting the same message, "No such pool".

The problem for me was that I was unable to import the pool (same as you) because one drive had changed it's device name.  Instead of doing a zpool import as a generic 'import all pools' specifying the pool name after the import command allowed the pool to be imported with one failed / missing drive.

So instead of typing 'zpool import' only, type 'zpool import your pool' and it will import.

This worked for me, then I was able to start with the drive replacement commands.